# Почему, нельзя создать, объект класса Integer?

Tags: java

```
public class Run {
    public static void main(String [] a) {
        Integer I = new Integer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) определено два конструктора — [`Integer(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer-int-)  и [`Integer(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer-java.lang.String-). Передав соответствующий аргумент, вы можете создать объект класса `Integer`. Конструктора без аргументов в классе нет, так что и вызов `Integer()` приведёт к ошибке компиляции

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), класс `Integer` не имеет конструктора без параметров. Необходимо в него подать либо целое число, либо строку, в которой целое число записано. То есть, варианта два:

```
Integer number = new Integer(25);
Integer anotherNumber = new Integer("26");
```

Answer (score 1):

Зайдите в сам класс [`Integer`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java) и вы найдете у него поле [`private final int value`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l840).

Также как и здесь - ВСЕ классы-обертки для примитивов имеют аналогичное поле, которое `final`, то есть неизменяемое.

Когда вы меняете значение уже созданного объекта класса `Integer` - фактически создается новый объект.